# How to install clang++?

Tags: gcc, clang

I'm having trouble getting clang++ to work as I compile my code. Specifically, I'm getting a `make: clang++: Command not found` error.

I've run `sudo apt-get install llvm`, and also `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and `sudo apt-get update`. What do I have to do to get clang++ installed?

Comment: Any Ubuntu 20 answer for C++20 ?

Comment: Step 1.: `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 44):

Installing the `llvm` and `build-essential` packages, as you have done, does not cause `clang` or `clang++` to be installed. For that, you must install [one of the clang packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=clang%2B%2B&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), depending on which version of `clang` and `clang++` you want.

### 16.04

In Ubuntu 16.04, your options are [clang-3.5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/clang-3.5), [clang-3.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/clang-3.6), [clang-3.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/clang-3.7), and [clang-3.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/clang-3.8).

### 14.04

In Ubuntu 14.04, your options are [clang-3.3 [image: Install clang-3.3]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang-3.3), [clang-3.4 [image: Install clang-3.4]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang-3.4), and [clang-3.5 [image: Install clang-3.5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang-3.5).

You can install them in the Software Center, or with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-3.n
```

(Replacing ***`n`*** with the desired sub-version, of course.)

### 12.04

If you're running Ubuntu 12.04, there's [only one package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=clang%2B%2B&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) that provides `clang` and `clang++`, so it's just called [clang [image: Install clang]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang).

Comment: is there a chance to install clang from source without sudo? after making and make check-all, i tried to use `make install`, but lots of permission denied appeared.

Comment: "clang-3.5" link produces "404 Page not found."

Comment: clang-3.6 is available on their download page for ubuntu 14.04: http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04.tar.xz

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII I don't know why that's happening. [The `clang-3.5` package does seem to exist for 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/clang-3.5), yet **you are right** that the Software Center link for it doesn't work. I don't have a 14.04 system to test this on right now. Can someone with (and with the universe repository enabled) check the output of `apt list clang\*`?

Comment: clang/trusty 1:3.4-0ubuntu1 amd64
 is the output of apt list clang.   And upon installing clang, I got this list as remarked to be install:    clang-3.4 libclang-common-3.4-dev libclang1-3.4 libobjc-4.8-dev libobjc4

Comment: With 14.04 (trusty-updates), [`clang-3.6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/clang-3.6) is also available.

Comment: At least for me, on 14.04 with `clang-3.8` installed, I added a soft link for clang++ (by default, I only had `/usr/bin/clang++-3.8`).  For example: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-3.8 /usr/bin/clang++`.

Comment: Can we get a more updated version of this answer?

Comment: @frank currently clang-5.0 is the newest version: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-5.0

Comment: @Amir Sure you can. `./configure --prefix $HOME/somewhere` Then when you `make` and `make install`, it installs it in your home directory where you said. Then you simply `PATH=$HOME/somewhere:$PATH`, and there you go, this terminal will find it. You can set your bash so it will just set PATH like that always, in your `.bashrc` or something.

Answer (score 27):

## 18.04 (Bionic)

I visited http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/dists/ (i.e. bionic distributions).
I determined that 6.0 was the latest major version of the toolchain.

I assume that you'll want the linker, lld, also.

```bash
# grab the key that LLVM use to GPG-sign binary distributions
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-6.0 main"
sudo apt-get install -y clang-6.0 lld-6.0
```

This gives you binaries with the following names (and more, probably):

```
clang-6.0
clang++-6.0
lld-6.0
ld.lld-6.0
```

It also installs these packages (and more):

```
llvm-6.0
llvm-6.0-dev
llvm-6.0-runtime
```

## 17.04 (Artful)

Same as above. I'll repeat every line for convenient copy-paste.

```bash
# grab the key that LLVM use to GPG-sign binary distributions
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/artful/ llvm-toolchain-artful-6.0 main"
sudo apt-get install -y clang-6.0 lld-6.0
```

## 16.04 (Xenial)

The accepted answer already gives instructions for installing clang-3.8 on 16.04, but here's how to get clang-6.0:

```bash
# grab the key that LLVM use to GPG-sign binary distributions
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-6.0 main"
sudo apt-get install -y clang-6.0 lld-6.0
```

Answer (score 9):

Before proceeding it will be worthwhile to update package information using
`sudo apt-get update`

**Installing Clang 9 on Ubuntu 18**

`sudo apt-get install clang-tools-9`

It will also install llvm-9

For more information follow [clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/Installation.html).

**Installing Clang 10 on Ubuntu 18**

`sudo apt-get install clang-tools-10`

Answer (score 2):

### 22.04LTS (Jammy)

```
sudo apt-get install -y clang-14 lld-14
```

Found latest release  here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/clang-14

Comment: This does not install clang++ as well, you need to run sudo apt install clang afterwards.

Comment: Not for me. Flutter demanded it and it only worked when i used simple `sudo apt install clang`