# Unmet dependencies when installing Clang++

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, dependencies, clang

I get the following error when trying to `sudo apt-get install` Clang++:

```
Note, selecting 'clang-tidy-4.0' for regex 'Clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-5.0' instead of 'python-clang-x.y'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

---

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-clang-3.5 : Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
python-clang-3.6 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
python-clang-3.7 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
python-clang-3.8 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
python-clang-3.9 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
python-clang-4.0 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.9 but 1:3.9.1-4ubuntu3~16.04.2 is to be installed
python-clang-5.0 : Breaks: python-clang-3.5 but 1:3.5.2-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.6 but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.7 but 1:3.7.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.8 but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-clang-3.9 but 1:3.9.1-4ubuntu3~16.04.2 is to be installed
```

I am unsure how to resolve these dependencies and don't know a good workaround for it. I am relatively new to Linux.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Any information would be appreciated. As far as I have been able to read here on the forums I should either remove the culprit program or upgrade it to the version that is needed. But from the error message I am unable to really gather what the culprit is in this case.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f`, then `sudo apt update` and try again

Comment: Have you tried, https://askubuntu.com/questions/509218/how-to-install-clang

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that there is no package `Clang++` or even `clang++`, so `apt` is treating the given name as a regular expression and trying to install **every** matching package - many of which conflict with each other:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --dry-run Clang++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'clang-modernize-5.0' for regex 'Clang+'
Note, selecting 'libclang-3.6-dev' for regex 'Clang+'
.
.
.
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.3' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.4' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.5' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.6' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.7' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.8' for regex 'clang+'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.9' for regex 'clang+'
.
.
.
```

In fact, unlike `gcc/g++`, `clang` provides both C and C++ compilers as a single package - you can install a specific version such as `clang-3.5` or simply install the highest-priority version for your system via the `clang` dependency package:

```
sudo apt install clang
```

See for example [How to install clang++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509218/how-to-install-clang)