# No .a or .o file created after building the project in Codelite

Tags: compiling, c++, g++, clang

I have installed Codelite and I have `g++` installed on my machine:

[image]

I've also used the following settings when creating a new codelite project

[image]

And I 've created a simple project

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when clicking `Build > Build Project`, I get the following Build report

```
/bin/sh -c 'make -j 8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ Hello_World - Release ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory             '/home/sepideh/Documents/new_workspace/Hello_World'
clang++  -c  "/home/sepideh/Documents/new_workspace/Hello_World/main.cpp" -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG  -o ./Release/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
/bin/sh: 1: clang++: not found
Hello_World.mk:95: recipe for target 'Release/main.cpp.o' failed
make[1]: *** [Release/main.cpp.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sepideh/Documents/new_workspace/Hello_World'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
make: *** [All] Error 2
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

And if I choose `Build > Run`, I'll get the following output report.

```
Current working directory: /home/sepideh/Documents/new_workspace/Hello_World/Release
Running program: /usr/lib/codelite/codelite_xterm './Hello_World ' '/bin/sh -f /usr/lib/codelite/codelite_exec ./Hello_World'
Program exited with return code: 0
```

[image]

I also had [a similar problem on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56446085/1245120) and the .exe file was not created.

Comment: Did you install `clang`?

Comment: @Jos I did now through [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065402/244993) have a look at [this photo](http://s3.picofile.com/file/8363367268/Screenshot_from_2019_06_12_15_25_28.png) and tell me if everything's OK?

Comment: Looks good to me, but try Codelite again to see if it really works.

Comment: @Jos no it didn't and i compiled the code with g++

Answer (score 2):

Install clang in 18.04 with the following command:

```
sudo apt install clang-6.0
```

#### Codelite

When you start a new console project select the *Simple executable (clang++)* Template. For Compiler (2 screens after the Select the project template screen) select *clang(tags/RELEASE_600/final)* or whatever clang version you have in the dropdown menu.

[image]

The results of *Build and Run Project*:

```
Hello World
Press ENTER to continue...
```

#### Terminal

The command clang is for C, and the command clang++ is for C++. The correct command for compiling hello.cpp with clang is:

```
clang++ hello.cpp
```

which results in an executable file named a.out

or

```
clang++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

which results in an executable file named hello.